# When does $\mathrm{End}(X)\cong X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I noticed in lecture that for any field $\mathbb F$, take the one-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F$ and write $\mathbb F\cong V\cong V^\ast=\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb F)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb F,\mathbb F)=\mathrm{End}(\mathbb F)$. This is a very basic case, so I'm just wondering, more generally, for what kinds of spaces $X$ is $\mathrm{End}(X)\cong X$?

Comment: Are you restricting your question to vector spaces?

Comment: Definitely not! I was trying to show this for certain types of rings, but totally failing.

Comment: In that case, your first problem is that your endomorphism object is rarely the same kind of object as $X$.

Comment: This is true for all commutative rings: $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R)\cong R^{op}$ for all rings, where the Hom is as $R$-modules. Commutativity gives $R\cong R^{op}$, so there you go.

Comment: I'm pretty embarrassed I missed such an immediate proof. My thought was that, since all fields are rings, I should start with, say, integral domains and try to use its properties.

Comment: @user10486601  This isn't something I'd be embarrassed over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "spaces," but here's a very general setup where you have an isomorphism of this sort. Consider a [closed monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) category, namely a category $M$ with a monoidal structure $\otimes$ and an internal hom $[-, -]$ fitting into an adjunction

$$\text{Hom}(a, [b, c]) \cong \text{Hom}(a \otimes b, c).$$

$\text{Vect}$ is such a category, with $\otimes$ the tensor product and $[-, -]$ the vector space of linear maps between two vector spaces. More generally, for $R$ a commutative ring, $\text{Mod}(R)$ is such a category, with $\otimes$ the tensor product over $R$ and $[-, -]$ the $R$-module of $R$-module homomorphisms between two $R$-modules.

> **Proposition:** The [unit object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unit+object) $1$ always satisfies $1 \cong [1, 1]$. More generally, every object $b$ satisfies $b \cong [1, b]$.

*Proof*. Follows immediately from the adjunction $\text{Hom}(a, [1, b]) \cong \text{Hom}(a \otimes 1, b) \cong \text{Hom}(a, b)$ together with the Yoneda lemma. $\Box$

Comment: A slightly stronger statement is that the unit object carries a canonical monoidal structure induced by the unit isomorphism $1 \otimes 1 \cong 1$, and we even have $1 \cong [1, 1]$ as monoids.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be any ring (commutative, with 1). Then $\text{End}_{R-\text{modules}}(R) = R$: any endomorphism $\phi$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(1)$ since $\phi(r) = r\phi(1)$, and $\phi(1)$ can be set to anything in $R$.